# how to detect form submit when it is done via a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, document

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<script>
    document.onsubmit = formSubmitted;

    function formSubmitted() {
        alert("formSubmitted");
    }

    function clickAction() {
        alert("clickAction");
        var aForm = document.forms['form2'];
        aForm.action = "#";
        aForm.submit();
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        <input type="submit" value="Direct Submit">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form name="form2" action="#$">
        <input type="button" value="Onclick Submit" Onclick="clickAction();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, I'm detecting form submit using document.onsubmit = formSubmitted;
alert is working.

but its not work when I tried to submit the form via javascript(click "Onclick Submit" button)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach that to a particular form.

```
document.form1.onsubmit = formSubmitted;
document.form2.onsubmit = formSubmitted;
```

Comment: This is not dynamic, then why not use document.onsubmit = formSubmitted;

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible. You'll need to extend your function `clickAction` to notify you when it has submitted the form.